# Extract data from hex CAN payload

Tags: python, hex, can-bus

Essentially I have this `.blf` file which has a bunch of CAN frames in hex.

In CAN, one frame has a bunch of message fields.

I'd like to grab the `Data` field.

For example: `1a01 2122 25f4 a187 ea80 2891 a223 4542`

Is a CAN frame. Somewhere in that frame is the Data message that I can convert into Decimal.

How do I go about recognizes which Hex codes contain the message?

Thanks in advnace

Comment: How exactly did you come to the conclusion that this hex goo of eight 16-bit chunks is a CAN frame? A classic CAN frame has up to 8 bytes data and 11 or 29 bit identifier. Then some fields containing size and status etc but you won't end up with 16 bytes even if you count CRC etc (which is handled by the CAN controller and irrelevant for the application).

Answer (score -1):

BLF format not only contains the data of the CAN frame, but also other information like the id of the application which created the BLF file, timestamps, arbitration id, etc.

Additionally the data could also be compressed.

As you have `python` in the tags, I'd suggest you take a look at [python-can](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html)
This library has support for reading and writing BLF files.